# Win7 Pro x64 task manager hangs when restarting explorer.exe after waking from sleep

Tags: windows-7, bios, freeze, sleep, network-adapter

I have a desktop running Windows 7 x64 Pro, set for Hybrid Sleep on a wired network.  Wakeup is only enabled from the keyboard (wake on mouse and Wake-On-LAN are both disabled).  Sometimes when it wakes up, there is no network connectivity.

The notification area icons for both network and volume don't respond to clicks.  If I open the Network and Sharing Center, clicking the red X doesn't do anything.

Restarting does fix the problem, but **I'm looking for a solution that does not require restarting (if at all possible)**.

Drivers are all up to date.

I've tried opening Task Manager and restarting the explorer.exe process, but Task Manager freezes for a few minutes, the "New Task" dialog closes, and explorer.exe has not restarted.  CPU and memory usage are both normal.

One thread suggested making sure the BIOS was set for S3 sleep mode only (not S1 or S1 & S3), but I haven't checked this yet.

Going back to sleep and waking back up does not help.  So far only a reboot has fixed the issue.

System specs:

```
Windows 7 x64 Pro  
Asus P8Z68-V PRO/GEN3  
128 GB Crucial m4 SSD  (Firmware version 0309)  
Intel Core i7 2600 3.4 GHz  
16 GB RAM
```

Comment: I wish I'd that much RAM :)